# Как изменить HTML внутри div span span на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Как изменить HTML внутри div span span на чистом JavaScript?
делаю пока так.

```
window.content.document.querySelector('._1mf').innerHTML = " Мой текст ";
```

Но он меняет Все в этом диве, спаны тоже удаляет. Подскажите как к ним добраться?

Вот сам код:

```
<div data-offset-key="22mje-0-0" class="_1mf">
   <span data-offset-key="22mje-0-0">
      <span data-text="true">Тут нужно текст HTML вставить </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('._1mf > span > span').innerHTML` ?

Comment: @Yuri спасибо оно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Через Query селектор можно обращаться на любой уровень **внутрь**

```
document.querySelector('._1mf > span > span').innerHTML = " Мой текст ";
```

2. Через старинный методы 20-го века до н.э. :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('_1mf')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = " Мой текст ";
```

Comment: Пссс, это CSS-селекторы, только никому, ОК?

Comment: На любой уровень **внутрь**, это важно.

Comment: @Other, Query :)

Comment: И что?.........